# How do I validate a form field in Codeigniter when using Get parameters?

Tags: forms, validation, codeigniter, post, get

I have a form that worked perfectly until I switched the form to `method="get"`.  Now I can't get `form_validation->run()` to evaluate to TRUE.

This is how I open the form:

```
echo form_open( '', array( 'method' => 'get' ) );
```

This is the only piece that needs to validate:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules( 'states', 'states', 'required' );
```

This is how I check to see if the form is validated:

```
if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE )
```

Is there something else I need to do to use Get parameters?  I have get parameters turned on in the config ( `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;` ).  The form works ok if I skip the validation, so I know the CI system is reading the url fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post on the Codeigniter Forum suggests that [form validation does not work with Get Parameters](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/193200/#911280) and that is just the way Codeigniter is.

Comment: Just step in and do your own validation on GET requests. XSS can be taken care of at the lowest level with htmlspecialchars(GET, ENT_QUOTES, 'encoding') depending on the data been output. Form validation is just a helper.  Work out your app structure before hand, see what CI can offer in relation to helpers/libraries and then mould your own workflow.

Comment: FYI ... Codeigniter form validation will fail if there are GET parameters in the URI of a page that is running form validation on POST parameters.

Answer (score 18):

For CodeIgniter 3, you can pass the GET array into the `set_data` function. For example:
`$this->form_validation->set_data($this->input->get());`

Comment: thanks it worked for me. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

Answer (score 7):

Just add:

```
$_POST['states'] = $this->input->get('states');
```

for validate states field in form validation just before

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('states', 'states', 'required|trim');
```

Answer (score 3):

Codeigniter has changed since some of these posts. I think gX's answer is correct.

The instructions in the user manual, specifically section [Validating an Array (other than $POST)](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post), worked great for me (as of today) and it's very simple.

Before your $this->form_validation->set_rules line, you specify the array to be validated:

```
$data = array(
    'username' => 'johndoe',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'passconf' => 'mypassword');

$this->form_validation->set_data($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on the Form_validation.php file, they have hardcoded $_POST everywhere in the class ;-(

If you want to support $_GET as well, it's quite easy (and dirty Oooo), you can create a new property :

```
public function __construct($rules = array())
{
    $this->inputData = array_merge($_POST, $_GET);
    ...
}
```

And replace $_POST by $this->inputData everywhere in this class since there is no static methods.

I know it's not recommenced to edit vendor files, but really, you need it, do it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to do exactly something similar but it boils down to the structure of your code.

1. Submit your form with the usual post method. This will allow you to carry out all post validations.
2. Then use the redirect() to send all your data to a different method within or outside your controller using '/'.
3. Finally, the method receiving all the parameters will handle the database transactions and present it to the view.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Validating an Array (other than $_POST)**

Sometimes you may want to validate an array that does not originate from $_POST data.

In this case, you can specify the array to be validated:

```
$data = array(
        'username' => 'johndoe',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'passconf' => 'mypassword'
);

$this->form_validation->set_data($data);
```

**NB. You have to call the set_data() method before defining any validation rules.**

Creating validation rules, running the validation, and retrieving error messages works the same whether you are validating $_POST data or another array of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file Form_validation.php to Form_get_validation.php and inside all the POST words rename to the words GET and name the class CI_Form_get_validation. when validating, call form_get_validation