# CodeIgniter Validation: possible to validate GET query strings?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

The form validation library seems to only work on POST. I need to use query strings and would like to use CI to validate the passed values. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can make CodeIgniter think it was from POST, even though it wasn't.  `$_POST = $_GET`, maybe?

Comment: lol, the whole class is hardcoded to use `$_POST`. So unless you completely override it, then no.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I validate a form field in Codeigniter when using Get parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524992/how-do-i-validate-a-form-field-in-codeigniter-when-using-get-parameters)

Comment: See my answer at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524992/how-do-i-validate-a-form-field-in-codeigniter-when-using-get-parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The current Codeigniter 3.0 development branch](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter) provides an option to insert your own variable instead of $_POST. So you could start using 3.0.

Alternatively, the only way in CI2.1 is to do $_POST=$_GET before you run the validation.

Comment: Could you please  provide the "option to insert your own variable instead of $_POST" ? Because i'm migrating to CI 3.0 and all my form_validation are working well except one. I receive GET values and i would like to validate them ... I don't know how to do, thanks !

Comment: I just found out what was the problem ... !!! In CI 3.0, they add a little check. Go to system/librairies/Form_validation.php. Search the "set_rules" function and delete the line : if ($this->CI->input->method() !== 'post' && empty($this->validation_data)) {
   return $this;
  }

Comment: Ive tried $_POST = $GET but the validation->run() still returns FALSE

Comment: You need to do `$_GET` not `$GET`

Comment: @Maxime I agree with you but I dont want to edit the codeigniter core code, did you find another way to do it ?

Comment: @NicolasThery sorry it was a long time ago I don't exactly remember. I think I just stick with that even if it was not the best solution obviously !

Answer (score 3):

See this page for the CodeIgniter 3 solution:-
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

For CodeIgniter 2 you can do $_POST = $_GET; before $this->form_validation->run() as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite the Form_validation function run in a MY_Form_Validation and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Reference [How do I validate a form field in Codeigniter when using Get parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524992/how-do-i-validate-a-form-field-in-codeigniter-when-using-get-parameters)

Before validation rules, set the validation data with the following code.

```
 $this->form_validation->set_data($_GET);
```