# Codeigniter form validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Here is my controller

```
  function register(){
        $_POST['username'] = $_GET['username'];
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required|trim|xss_clean|min_length[5]');
        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {

        }
        var_dump(form_error('username'));
}
```

Can I test this funtion with home/register?username=test ???
I tried but it not working

Comment: You mean `http://localhost/home/register?username=test`?

Comment: yes,I want test this and echo form_error :D

Comment: check these links [stack question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883949/codeigniter-validation-possible-to-validate-get-query-strings)
[stack question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524992/how-do-i-validate-a-form-field-in-codeigniter-when-using-get-parameters)

Comment: it should work, but only if your controller is Home.php or if you have a route that's pointing to that "register" function

Comment: What is the point of this line??? ` $_POST['username'] = $_GET['username'];`

Answer (score 0):

Well, apart from you question being a bit confusing, I think the answer is no. You cannot test a post request with a get request from url parameters.

The way to test a post request is to post the required test data.

I am pretty sure that is correct, however, as I said your question was a bit confusing so if I am missing your point, I apologize in advance.

If you want to test validation NOT from a post, you can use the validation rules on any array.

```
$data = array(
    'username' => 'johndoe',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'passconf' => 'mypassword'
);

$this->form_validation->set_data($data);
```

You can read more about that here: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post